# False the value except the selected radio button using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, radio-button

I using **radio** button within my angular page. The radio button is under the `ng-repeat`. I want to check the radio default by the json data is `true`. Then if one radio checked, change the remaining data into be a `false`. i done it. But radio button is not checked in the UI.

[Here a fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/satheeshsanthosh/hgxjv/385/)

I Hope you understand this and what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `$scope.setChoiceForQuestion` to:

```
$scope.setChoiceForQuestion = function (q, c) {        
   angular.forEach(q, function (r) {
        if(c != r)
        r.isUserAnswer = false;
    });
};
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-checked="choise.isUserAnswer || choise.isUserAnswer === 'true'"` for check and uncheck element instead of `ng-model="choice.isUserAnswer"`
compare with `'true'` because in json you have string. Or you can change json "true" and "false" to `true` and `false` without double quotes and leave in condition just `ng-checked="choise.isUserAnswer"`.

[Here a fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/8532110_idej/nr1m4vyh/2/)